# Android: How to get access to POI data from Mapbox

Tags: android, openstreetmap, mapbox

Question: Is it possible to get access to the OSM data like POI on Android?

I would like to find POI's within a certain distance from a position on the map.

Comment: Did you already take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)?

Comment: No I haven't, thank you for that. However, I'm wondering if it's possible with the Mapbox API only.